# Get PID of highest memory consuming process with nvidia-smi

Tags: awk, nvidia

Currently I have a little bash script that sums up the
vram usage of all processes.

```
nvidia-smi | awk '{print $6}'| awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

But now I want to get the PID of the process that uses the most VRAM.
After that I would like to get the user of the PID with

```
ps -u -p $pid
```

EDIT currently my nvidia-smi looks like this:
I want to get the PID 29187 because this PID uses the most vram(3649MB)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 35%   43C    P8    36W / 250W |   5012MiB / 11016MiB |     15%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      5512      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           257MiB |
|    0      5786      G   kwin_x11                                      77MiB |
|    0      5790      G   /usr/bin/krunner                               6MiB |
|    0      5800      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                         114MiB |
|    0     26439      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            73MiB |
|    0     26457      G   /usr/bin/sddm-greeter                        132MiB |
|    0     29154    C+G   .../Binaries/Linux/CarlaUE4-Linux-Shipping   619MiB |
|    0     29187      C   python                                      3649MiB |
|    0     29999      G   /opt/ros/melodic/lib/rviz/rviz                62MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Alternatively as an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypVza.png

Final Script in which it works.

```
sum=$(nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6} NR>14 && 
0+$6>MAX{MAX=0+$6;MAXSTRING=$6;MAXPID=$3} END{printf SUM;}')

maxpid=$(nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6} NR>14 && 
0+$6>MAX{MAX=0+$6;MAXSTRING=$6;MAXPID=$3} END{printf MAXPID;}')

if [ $sum -lt 8000 ]
then
    hostname | tr -d '\n'
    echo ' 'AVAILABLE vram  $sum 
else 
    hostname | tr -d '\n'
    user=$(ps -u -p $maxpid| awk '{print$1}'| awk 'FNR == 2 {print}')
    echo ' 'false, $user is responsible
fi
```

Comment: Could you please post output of `nvidia-smi` in your post and let us know, so that we could get better understanding on this question then.

Comment: `awk '{print $6}'| awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'` isn't giving you a good total. It's summing the `Driver Version` in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your two `awk` statements and also fix the issue where it adds the numbers in the `Driver Version:` into your total like so:

```
nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6}END{print SUM}'
```

That only considers the row if it's greater than row 14 (where the data you care about lives.

Adding some logic to grab the max and print out the process:

```
nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6} NR>14 && 0+$6>MAX{MAX=0+$6;MAXSTRING=$6;MAXPID=$3} END{print SUM,MAXPID,MAXSTRING}'
```

That will print out the sum, the PID that had the max GPU Memory Usage and that Memory Usage.

This breaks down though if `GPU Memory Usage` can switch units (like between `MiB` and `KiB`).

Comment: First of all thanks for this code. But Im struggling to get the user from this. Currently my code looks like this. blame_and_shame() {
    echo blame user
    ps -u -p $1
}

nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6} NR>14 && 0+$6>MAX{MAX=0+$6;MAXSTRING=$6;MAXPID=$3} END{if (SUM < 11000) printf"used vram = " SUM "\n"; else blame_and_shame MAXPID;}'

Comment: I missed that step. You can store the pid to a variable like `pid=$(nvidia-smi | awk 'NR>14{SUM+=$6} NR>14 && 0+$6>MAX{MAX=0+$6;MAXSTRING=$6;MAXPID=$3} END{print MAXPID}')` And then use that in your next command like `ps -u -p $pid`. You could also pipe to `xargs` and use that to toss the `pid` over to `ps` in one long command, but that would get ugly to debug if anything goes awry.

Comment: Thanks yeah I managed to do it with xargs and then it works, but the problem is, that I want to do it in an if else. So I don't want to always print the user. I edited my question

Comment: Gotcha. I would have awk print out both the sum and the maxpid parsing both into their own shell variables. Then you can do your `if` out in the shell where it makes more sense. Like use `awk` to parse and math your file and use bash or whatever to take care of the resulting logic.

Answer (score 1):

For a more efficient parsing involving all the SI metric units `KiB` and `GiB` you can do something below. This needs GNU `awk` for array sorting functionality

```
awk '
$6 ~ /[M|K|G]iB/ {
    if ( index( $6, "KiB" ) ) { gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $6); ram = ($6+0) * 1024 }
    if ( index( $6, "MiB" ) ) { gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $6); ram = ($6+0) * 1024 * 1024 }
    if ( index( $6, "GiB" ) ) { gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $6); ram = ($6+0) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }
    usage += ram
    map[$3] = ram
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    printf "Total RAM Usage = %s\n",((usage/1024)/1024)"MiB"
    for (i in map) {
        printf "Highest RAM Usage PID = %d Value = %s\n", i, ((map[i]/1024)/1024)"MiB"
        break
    }
}'
```